# Angular 2 and Laravel 5.3 API call error on OPTIONS request error on ajax call

Tags: angular, laravel-5

I am building a api service using laravel and a client in angular 2. When I try to submit a form as JSON data it gives preflight error. I tested the api using potman extension and it is working and gets 200 status code but when  angular sends a OPTIONS request first it gets 301. Please help me with this situation.

[image: Postman Extention getting 200]

Angular App :

[image: Angular 2 Request and Errors in console]

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors

This fixed my issue. Laravel 5.3 and angular 2

Hope this helps someone else